# Can Blender Bezier spline curves be G2 continuous?

Tags: bezier-curves

Are Blender Bezier spline curves [G2 continuous](https://www.aliasworkbench.com/theoryBuilders/TB3_continuity1.htm) when the *Handle Type* is set to *Automatic*?